# neo4j - get attribute value from multiple related objects into one return row

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following situation:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.Type IN ['a', 'b', 'c'] WITH n OPTIONAL MATCH (f)-[:PART_OF]->(n) RETURN CASE WHEN n.Type = a THEN f.attribute WHEN n.Type = b then f.attribute1 ELSE '' END, n.type
```

I want one single row returned even if `n` has multiple objects related to it.

The below solution is not enough because I don't know the exact number of related objects. There could be `1..n` relations from `(f) - [:part_of] -> (n)`:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.Type IN ['a', 'b', 'c'] WITH n OPTIONAL MATCH (f)-[:PART_OF]->(n) WITH n, COLLECT({ftype: f.Type, fsubType:f.SubType}) AS ff RETURN CASE WHEN n.Type = a AND ff[0].ftype = x THEN 'z' .....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATCH (n) WHERE n.Type IN ['x', 'y']
WITH n OPTIONAL MATCH (f)-[:PART_OF]->(n)
WITH n, COLLECT({ftype: f.Type, fsubtype:f.SubType, flocalipaddr: f.LocalIpAddr, fip: f.IP, fremotetunnelendpoint: f.RemoteTunnelEndpoint, fpeername: f.PEERNAME}) AS fcp
WITH n, fcp, [x IN fcp WHERE x.ftype = 'IKEP' AND  x.fsubtype = 'Security Gateway' and n.SubType = 'eNodeB'| x.fpeername]  AS fpeername,
[x IN fcp WHERE x.ftype = 'DEVIP' AND  x.fsubtype = 'SYNC' and n.SubType = 'eNodeB'| x.fip]  AS fip
RETURN 'Base Station' AS OptType, n.SubType, fpeername[0], fip[0]